# ROOTpy plottin color not working in example directory

Tags: rootpy

I have installed rootpy and matplotlib.

But when I trying to run plot_matplotlib_hist.py in example directory, matplotlib canvas color was OK but the color of ROOT canvas only dark.
It does not same color between matplotlib and ROOT.

Comment: Post your code otherwise it's impossible to help you

Comment: I think "plot_matplotlib_hist.py in example directory" refers to [this file](https://github.com/rootpy/rootpy/blob/master/examples/plotting/plot_matplotlib_hist.py) shipped by rootpy. That said, works for me.

Comment: thank you for yours answer. but "https://github.com/rootpy/rootpy/blob/master/examples/plotting/plot_matplotlib_hist.py", this code also only black and white print out.